# Scrapy Error. List index out of range

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm pretty new to web-scraping and I'm currently trying to employ Scrapy into a Tensorflow project I'm working on but for some reason Scrapy is not giving me any results. I believe I'm doing something wrong when extracting the actual link to an image or the title itself. I stumbled across an example of extracting images from imgur so that's what I'm currently working with.

Items.py

```
import scrapy

class ImgurItem(scrapy.Item):

    title = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'imgur'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['imgur.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'imgur.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'imgur.pipelines.ImgurPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = 'I:\ScrapySpiders\imgur\imgur\Images'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

imgur_spider.py

```
 import scrapy

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from imgur.items import ImgurItem

class ImgurSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'imgur'
    allowed_domains = ['imgur.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.imgur.com']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/gallery/.*']), 'parse_imgur')]

    def parse_imgur(self, response):
        image = ImgurItem()
        image['title'] = response.xpath("//h1[@class='post-title']/text()").extract()
        rel = response.xpath("//img/@src").extract()
        image['image_urls'] = ['http:'+rel[0]]
        return image
```

pipelines.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline

class ImgurPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def set_filename(self, response):
        #add a regex here to check the title is valid for a filename.
        return 'full/{0}.jpg'.format(response.meta['title'][0])

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url, meta={'title': item['title']})

    def get_images(self, response, request, info):
        for key, image, buf in super(ImgurPipeline, self).get_images(response, request, info):
            key = self.set_filename(response)
        yield key, image, buf
```

UPDATED ERROR LOG:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\tomas\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\files.py", line 356, in media_downloaded
    checksum = self.file_downloaded(response, request, info)
  File "c:\users\tomas\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\images.py", line 98, in file_downloaded
    return self.image_downloaded(response, request, info)
  File "c:\users\tomas\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\images.py", line 102, in image_downloaded
    for path, image, buf in self.get_images(response, request, info):
  File "I:\ScrapySpiders\imgur\imgur\pipelines.py", line 24, in get_images
    key = self.set_filename(response)
  File "I:\ScrapySpiders\imgur\imgur\pipelines.py", line 16, in set_filename
    return 'full/{0}.jpg'.format(response.meta['title'][0])
IndexError: list index out of range
2017-11-19 22:11:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://imgur.com/gallery/pKsYl>
{'image_urls': ['http://i.imgur.com/YEQb03D.jpg'], 'images': [], 'title': []}
2017-11-19 22:11:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://imgur.com/gallery/R6eQD> (referer: None)
2017-11-19 22:11:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://imgur.com/gallery/QrKeE>
{'image_urls': ['http://i.imgur.com/OpDDRWr.png'], 'images': [], 'title': []}
2017-11-19 22:11:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://imgur.com/gallery/JKz3U>
{'image_urls': ['http://i.imgur.com/VChqgP9r.jpg'], 'images': [], 'title': []}
{'image_urls': ['http://i.imgur.com/m9Cq6B1.png'], 'title': []}
2017-11-19 22:11:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://i.imgur.com/m9Cq6B1.png> (referer: None)
2017-11-19 22:11:27 [scrapy.pipelines.files] DEBUG: File (downloaded): Downloaded file from <GET http://i.imgur.com/m9Cq6B1.png> referred in <None>
2017-11-19 22:11:27 [PIL.PngImagePlugin] DEBUG: STREAM b'IHDR' 16 13
2017-11-19 22:11:27 [PIL.PngImagePlugin] DEBUG: STREAM b'IDAT' 41 8192
2017-11-19 22:11:28 [scrapy.pipelines.files] ERROR: File (unknown-error): Error processing file from <GET http://i.imgur.com/m9Cq6B1.png> referred in
<None>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\tomas\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "c:\users\tomas\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
  File "c:\users\tomas\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1363, in returnValue
    raise _DefGen_Return(val)
twisted.internet.defer._DefGen_Return: <200 http://i.imgur.com/m9Cq6B1.png>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\tomas\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\files.py", line 356, in media_downloaded
    checksum = self.file_downloaded(response, request, info)
  File "c:\users\tomas\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\images.py", line 98, in file_downloaded
    return self.image_downloaded(response, request, info)
  File "c:\users\tomas\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\images.py", line 102, in image_downloaded
    for path, image, buf in self.get_images(response, request, info):
  File "I:\ScrapySpiders\imgur\imgur\pipelines.py", line 24, in get_images
    key = self.set_filename(response)
  File "I:\ScrapySpiders\imgur\imgur\pipelines.py", line 16, in set_filename
    return 'full/{0}.jpg'.format(response.meta['title'][0])
IndexError: list index out of range
2017-11-19 22:11:28 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://imgur.com/gallery/R6eQD>
{'image_urls': ['http://i.imgur.com/m9Cq6B1.png'], 'images': [], 'title': []}
2017-11-19 22:11:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-11-19 22:11:28 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 1,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/builtins.ValueError': 1,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 29607,
 'downloader/request_count': 122,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 122,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 14490175,
 'downloader/response_count': 121,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 115,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 2,
 'file_count': 45,
 'file_status_count/downloaded': 45,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 19, 20, 11, 28, 247434),
 'item_scraped_count': 68,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 274,
 'log_count/ERROR': 46,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'log_count/WARNING': 3,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 115,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 76,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 76,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 76,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 76,
 'spider_exceptions/IndexError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 19, 20, 11, 21, 643056)}
2017-11-19 22:11:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I'm aware that there are similar threads that specify issues with this exact code but none of them were able to help me and fix the problem I encountered. Apprently Imgur changes the web coding and I just can't figure out how should I extract these links

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why there is a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267729/why-there-is-a-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a new answer to clean things up. This should work:

Modify `parse_imgur` function to:

```
def parse_imgur(self, response):
    image = ImgurItem()
    image['title'] = response.xpath("//h1[contains(@class, 'post-title')]/text()").extract_first()
    rel = response.xpath("//img/@src").extract_first()
    try:
        image['image_urls'] = ['http:'+rel]
        return image
    except:
        pass
```

Notice that the `h1` class name have a space at the end. You could use `@class="post-title "`, or my preferred way using `contains(@class, 'post-title')`

Since I'm using `.extract_first()` for the image title, you should also modify the following:

```
def set_filename(self, response):
    return 'full/{0}.jpg'.format(response.meta['title'][0])
```

to:

```
def set_filename(self, response):
    return 'full/{0}.jpg'.format(response.meta['title'])
```

Other improvements could be to sanitize the filenames and the class selector for the post title (e.g it will also select class with name `long-post-title` and `post-title-again`).

Comment: And so it did. Thank you very much for your patience.I have a few parting questions though since I'm determined to learn scrapy. How does extract differ from extract first? And why removing list from rel worked using this method?

Comment: Glad I could help. Using `extract()` will give you a list of strings (if there are any), while `extract_first()` will only extract the first item that matches the selector and return a simple string (not a list). In general if you only expect a single item to be found by your selector I would recommend using `extract_first()` since you avoid any indexing issues when trying to index an empty variable.

Comment: Great! Thank you heaps again for asisting me in this!

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with web scraping or imgur. You're getting a python syntax error at the beginning of this line:

```
rel = response.xpath("//img[@src='//i.imgur.com/*.*'])".extract()
```

This is because you have two opening parens but only one closing paren on the preceding line:

```
#                              v
image['title'] = response.xpath(\
    "//h1[@class='post-title']/text()".extract()
#                                             ^^
```

The opening paren in `response.xpath(` is unbalanced.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I feel really silly right now. However, after fixing basic syntax errors(few more came up later) I came across another problem that I was looking in to a little while before this post. It seems my code loses objects somewhere along the way. I'm getting list index out of range error:

image['image_urls'] = ['http:'+rel[0]]
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Just move the quotation mark to the correct side of the closing parenthesis and it should work for you:

```
rel = response.xpath("//img[@src='//i.imgur.com/*.*']").extract()
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing. Really questioning my focus at the moment, although after fixing it I received an out of index error at  image['image_urls'] = ['http:'+rel[0]]

Comment: This could happen if your `rel` variable ends up empty and you try to reference the first index of an empty variable. I would rewrite to `rel = response.xpath("//img[@src='//i.imgur.com/*.*']").extract_first()` and remove the index from `image['image_urls'] = ['http:'+rel[0]]` so that it becomes `image['image_urls'] = ['http:'+rel]`

Comment: Weirdly enough your solution end up with "cannot convert nonetype object to str implicitly" while fixing the syntax previously would error out at pipelines.py file with an out of index error. Your solutions seems more logical to me as well but I'm getting progressively more confused haha

Comment: Ahh.. That makes sense. If the `rel` variable is empty it's not a good idea to convert it into a string. You could use a try-except statement. `try: image['image_urls'] = ['http:'+rel] except: image['image_urls'] = None`. You need to take care of newline and tabs since I cannot properly format in this comment. You can also change `None` to for example a string of your choice.

Comment: Just another thought. Sometimes we end up with a few empty values when crawling, which could be considered normal depending on the website you're crawling. However, if all of your image links end up empty, then there are something more fundamentally wrong with the crawler.

Comment: Great thoughts, I'll give it a try soon. And about the crawler itself. It seemed to work for people at the release of the tutorial I'm trying to follow but now I have to modify it so it would fit the current situation which is why I might be doing something incredibly wrong. My guess is that I cannot properly extract titles/images or feed them into a pipeline in a proper manner.